# Need to install MIT KDC in All hadoop Nodes in the cluster For Kerberos Authentication?

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, ambari, kdc

I have a 5 nodes Hadoop cluster(Hortonworks). I am doing kerborised authentication using MIT KDC and Ambari. In my every node my hostname like xxx.trinityiot.cloud. here my doubt is Either I need to install MIT KDC in every node or in Ambari server node os enough.

```
I have tried before in Single node using MIT KDC and Ambari and tested all Hadoop components like HBase Kafka etc. Now my Doubt is Either I need to install MIT KDC in all Hadoop nodes or Ambari server node is enough.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have krb5-workstation in all the nodes and KDC running in one host that runs as the Kerberos server.

**In Master node:**

For instlalling KDC and krb5-workstation - `yum install krb5*`

**In All nodes:**

For installing krb5-workstation - `yum install krb5-workstation`

This might help - https://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/www/krb5-latest/doc/admin/install_kdc.html

Comment: I am using the Hortonworks Hadoop cluster. I am following a link to enable Kerberos authentication for a single node.

Comment: I am using the below link                                                        https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/authentication-with-kerberos/content/kerberos_optional_install_a_new_mit_kdc.html                                                             I have to enable in 5 node cluster. I have enabled KDC in a master node  I didn't install in remaining nodes.

Comment: My krb.conf file is below    [realms]
 HUB.M01 = {
  kdc = trinity.hub.m01
  kdc = trinity.hub.s01
  kdc = openpaas.local
  admin_server = trinity.hub.mo1
 }